# Does Mathematica have built-in support for multivariate regression?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I know that `LinearModelFit` can generate a model of a single response variable as a function of a set in input variables.  Does *Mathematica* provide support for matrix regression, i.e. multiple inputs, multiple response variables?

Comment: i.e. something equivalent to the function lm() in R

Comment: Could you show some data and a model as an example?

Comment: LinearModelFit[{m,v}] constructs a linear model from the design matrix m and response vector v.

Comment: `LinearModelFit` complains if `v` is not a list of real numbers, so if you mean is there a built-in function that does the type of multivariate regression discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/254254), I think the answer is no.  At least I couldn't find one.

Comment: For instance in R, one can analyze the linear relationship of several response variables to several predictor variables: E.g. `mlm1 <- lm(cbind(TOT, AMI) ~ GEN + AMT + PR + DIAP + QRS, data = ami_data)`, from [here](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/), where the responses are `TOT`, `AMI` and the predictors are `GEN`, `AMT`, `PR`, `DIAP`, `QRS`.

Answer (score 5):

While the terms multivariate and multiple are sometimes confused, in regression, those who make a distinction tend to call many outputs *multivariate* and many inputs *multiple*. `LinearModelFit` does univariate multiple regression, but not multivariate regression.

Here is the example from the U.Va. site I linked in a comment:

```
amiData = Import["http://static.lib.virginia.edu/statlab/materials/data/ami_data.DAT"]
```

Each row consists of values for the variables

```
{TOT, AMI, GEN, AMT, PR, DIAP, QRS}
```

The problem is to analyze the linear relationship between the response `{TOT, AMI}` and predictors `{GEN, AMT, PR, DIAP, QRS}`.  The underlying model consists of two linear equations, which are the same whether doing univariate and multivariate analysis. Thus they can be obtained from separate calls to `LinearModelFit`:

```
(* individual univariate regressions *)
vars = {GEN, AMT, PR, DIAP, QRS};
totLM = LinearModelFit[amiData[[All, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1}]], vars, vars]
amiLM = LinearModelFit[amiData[[All, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2}]], vars, vars]
```

The coefficients of the linear model may be obtained from each of these linear models or in a multivariate way via `LeastSquares[]`:

```
{totLM["BestFitParameters"], amiLM["BestFitParameters"]} // Transpose
LeastSquares[  (* multivariate approach to the regression equation *)
 PadLeft[N@amiData[[All, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]], {Automatic, 6}, 1.],
 amiData[[All, {1, 2}]]
 ]
(*
{{-2879.48, -2728.71}, {675.651, 763.03}, {0.284851, 
  0.306373}, {10.2721, 8.8962}, {7.25117, 7.20556}, {7.59824, 4.98705}}

{{-2879.48, -2728.71}, {675.651, 763.03}, {0.284851, 
  0.306373}, {10.2721, 8.8962}, {7.25117, 7.20556}, {7.59824, 4.98705}}
*)
```

So far, so good.  If that's all you want, then you can use separate calls to `LinearModelFit` to do independent univariate multiple regressions.

However, if you want to use [Multivariate ANOVA (MANOVA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance) to compare variables across models, then I think there is no support for that.  The [ANOVA package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/tutorial/ANOVA.html) does not seem to handle MANOVA nor does `LinearModelFit`.  However, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_statistical_packages) indicates that *Mathematica* can handle MANOVA.  Perhaps they mean if you write the code yourself.  [This Community discussion](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/53970) is about the OP's question, but I don't think it really addresses MANOVA.

You can use [RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html) to call R.  The [car package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) contains the `Manova` command.  I had to follow the protocol [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173070/rlink-no-longer-works-with-r-3-5-on-macos) to get *Mathematica* and R to play nicely together on my Mac. 
I was able to go through the [U.Va. example](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/), but the R output is translated back into *Mathematica* with lots of inconvenient `RObject[..]` wrappers.  To parse it, I had to look simultaneously at R, which knows how to interpret the data structure and displays it in tables with meaningful headers.  Somewhat of a headache.  If I really needed to do this a lot, I'd write my own *Mathematica* functions.