# Installing R for use with V11.3 on Windows 10

Tags: probability-or-statistics, warning-messages, installation, rlink

I can't install R on Windows 10. I tried some solutions that I found on the Internet, but they did not help.

```
Needs["RLink`"]
JLink`UninstallJava[]
InstallR[
  "RHomeLocation" -> "X:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1", 
  "NativeLibLocation" -> 
  "X:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1\\library\\rJava\\jri\\x64"]
```

During evaluation of the above, I get

> InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries
>
> $Failed

Comment: Wolfram support will likely be better able to help than will we. Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't received an answer yet.

Comment: There are actually two issues here: incompatibility with the more recent versions of R, and the bug that requires to call `InstallR[]` twice at first, for every session. Both have been fixed for 12.0. For the dll issues, you can use the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173070/rlink-no-longer-works-with-r-3-5-on-macos) for the workaround. You will need to go to R console (for your R distro), and call `install.packages("rJava")` from there. Next, go to installed `rJava` package and locate there `jri.dll` in `JRI` folder, for your architecture (64 bit, I presume)...

Comment: Then use that location, for the setting of `"NativeLibLocation"` (look at the answer I linked). That should take care of the library issue. As to the other one, you will need to call `InstallR[...]` followed immediately by `UninstallR[]`, and then `InstallR[]` again, at the start of the R session. After that, everything should work. Let me know if that does not work for you, I will look closer (don't have 11.3 installed at the moment). Sorry for this state of affairs, I should've fixed these issues earlier.

Comment: Actually, I see that you already worked around the libraries issues. So then, you just need to call `InstallR[...]` and then immediately follow by `UninstallR[]`. Then call `InstallR[]` again, and things should work.

Comment: @b3m2a1 "Wolfram support will likely be better able to help than will we. Have you tried contacting them?" - correct in general, but in this particular case this path will likely lead to me, unless they have these workarounds available.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for your comments and answers. I will certainly try this way to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of reading @szabolcs [RLink link](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html#macOSr35) which has the following:

> Unfortunately, with recent versions of Mathematica and R on macOS,
>   occasionally the R runtime crashes on the first use of REvaluate, and
>   the following message is shown: “Crash in low-level RLink component or
>   in R runtime. Please reinstall RLink via InstallR”. After using
>   InstallR[] a second time, RLink seems to work fine.

the following then seems to get things working for me on Windows 10 with *Mathematica* 11.3:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.4"]
REvaluate["x = 6"]

(* REvaluate::crash: Crash in low-level RLink component or in R runtime.
   Please reinstall RLink via InstallR *)

InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.4"]
```

Now all subsequent `RLink` commands work.

Comment: I tried this command, but "InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries".