# Error using InstallR from RLink`

Tags: rlink

I am writing the code

```
Needs["RLink`"]
RLinkResourcesinstall[]
```

and I obtained the output

```
Out[3]= {PacletObject[RLinkRuntime, 9.0.0.0, <>]}
```

Then I tried to install R with InstallR and the output is $Failed
[image]

I have Windows 10 and the my version of Mathematica 12.1. Any help to solve this error would be appreciated. Thanks.

Also tried to specify the path with

[image]

Comment: The bundled R is being worked on (to update it to version 3.6.x). For the external R, the 12.1.1 version is coming soon which will contain library updates including 3.6.3. But You don't have to wait for that, you can use the procedure described [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1807709) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173070/rlink-no-longer-works-with-r-3-5-on-macos).